# Wrong limit appears

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the following limit
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}x-\sqrt{x^2+7x}
$$
Going through some algebra leads to
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}x-\sqrt{x^2+7x}&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{(x-\sqrt{x^2+7x})(x+\sqrt{x^2+7x})}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+7x})}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-7x}{x+\sqrt{x^2+7x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-7}{1+\sqrt{1+7/x}}=-\frac72
\end{align}$$
However, *Mathematica* yields

```
Limit[x-Sqrt[x^2+7x], x -> -Infinity]
Out[]= -∞
```

I looked into the step-by-step solution, which relied on power rules of limits, but couldn't find the problem. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Maybe something with the way *Mathematica* handles certain limits?

Comment: You don't have cancelation at -infinity...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mistake lies in your derivation.
You use the partial squareroot
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+7x}}{x}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+7x}{x^2}}$$

However, this only holds for positive x. You essentially jump a branch cut to the positive solution. Mathematica is aware of this:

```
Limit[Sqrt[7x+x^2]/x,x->-Infinity]
Limit[Sqrt[(7x+x^2)/x^2],x->-Infinity]
```

> -1
>
> 1

With the real solution of `-1` you approach a division by zero from the positive side. This, combined with the `-7` in the numerator then approaches `-Infinity` as given from mathematica.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah ok! So Mathematica is actually correct, right? It is indeed $-\infty$?

Comment: Yes Mathematica is correct here.